# Http with .html to https without html in one redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying rewrite our website's htaccess file. I'm not too good with htaccess but I'm studying our existing .htaccess file, right now what I understand is that we have htaccess directives that redirects http to https.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And another right below that redirects from a request having a .html extension into no .html.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure, but does R=301 mean redirect?
If so, is it doing a redirect after each match in the rewritecond?
And is there a way that I can create another directive that matches both conditions before trying to redirect to both rules?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single redirect rule for both `301` redirects:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html\s [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:\.html)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but there are still 2 R=301

Comment: Yes, but there was never more than one executed